# Java: Mi archivo no se compila ni corre

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo un programa de practica donde debo usar un ciclo for para q se de la siguiente sucesion de numeros:
1,99,2,98,3,97

Este es la imagen de mi editor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras compilar, en la consola solo sale ese mensaje pero no ejecuta nada del codigo escrito :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de que no te aparezca nada es que en el segundo for indicas como condición que j<=0 pero j tiene valor 100 así que nunca entraría dentro de ese for.
Se solucionaria poninedo que j>=0 y te funcionaria.
Ademas lo que estas intentando no funcionaria como tu esperas ya que la salida seria 1,99,98,97.... 2,99,98,97....3,99,98,97 y asi hasta llegar al 100,99,...,1.
Lo que te piden se logragria con un solo bucle for tal que asi:

```
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        System.out.print(i+","+(100-i)+",");
    }
```